# opposite of sql IN() statement

Tags: php, sql

What is the opposite of the IN() sql statement. How would i structure the following statement to pull all records except 2,5, and 6. An "!" right before IN doesn't work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN('2','5','6')";
```

Comment: NOT IN should work. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT IN('2','5','6')";
```

**EDIT :**

As pointed out by 'onedaywhen' and 'ypercube' in comments,

For **Null Allowed** columns you may need to add

```
OR column IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
OR column IS NULL
```

Comment: It's not quite the 'opposite' when you consider nulls.

Comment: As @onedaywhen comments, *"all records except 2,5, and 6"* is NOT equivalent to `column NOT IN('2','5','6')` for a nullable column.